# Ruby app doesn't seem to find my facebook friends

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku, sinatra, koala

My fiancee and I are building our [wedding website](https://deboandnikhilwedding.com/). It's a sinatra app, and we are using koala for facebook integration.

We only want our friends to be able to RSVP. The app will return friends who use it. Since both of us are using and developing it, we should see each other in the friends returned. Here's how I fetch the profile information and friends:

```
def get_fb_profile
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session['access_token'])
  profile = graph.get_object('me')
  friends = graph.get_connections('me','friends')
  return [profile, friends]
end
```

Here is what I'm logging:

```
@profile , @friends = get_fb_profile
p @profile
p @friends
```

However, the `friends` array always seems to be empty. We marked the application live and are not using any extended permissions. Here are the relevant log statements from heroku:

```
2015-03-08T06:50:08.340151+00:00 app[web.1]: {"id"=>"XX", "first_name"=>"MyFirstName", "gender"=>"male", "last_name"=>"MyLastName", "link"=>"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/XX/", "locale"=>"en_US", "name"=>"MyFirstName MyLastName", "timezone"=>-5, "updated_time"=>"2014-11-02T03:15:32+0000", "verified"=>true}
2015-03-08T06:50:08.340218+00:00 app[web.1]: []
```

The full source is at [github](https://github.com/nikhilbhardwaj/WeddingWebsite).

Comment: Can you please tell me why my question was down voted and also how I can improve the same? Thanks.

Comment: For a live app, you need to have the user_friends permission approved. Have you done that? Does it work when your app is in development mode? Can you check that you have the user_friends permission? You can do that by calling `me/permissions`. If this is not the issue, can you post your app id?